# PHP not Sending JSON Object to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    if(isset($_POST['limit'])){
        $limit = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_POST['limit']);
        require_once("connect_db.php");
        $i = 0;
        $jsonData = '{';
        $sqlString = "SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $limit";
        $query = mysqli_query($con, $sqlString) or die (mysqli_error()); 
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $i++;
            $id = $row["id"]; 
            $title = $row["title"];
            $cd  = $row["creationdate"];
            $cd = strftime("%B %d, %Y", strtotime($cd));
            $jsonData .= '"article'.$i.'":{ "id":"'.$id.'","title":"'.$title.'", "cd":"'.$cd.'"  },';
        }
        $now = getdate();
        $timestamp = $now[0];
        $jsonData .= '"arbitrary":{"itemcount":'.$i.', "returntime":"'.$timestamp.'"}';
        $jsonData .= '}';
        echo $jsonData;
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var myTimer;
            function ajax_json_data(){
            var databox = document.getElementById("databox");
            var arbitrarybox = document.getElementById("arbitrarybox");
            var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            hr.open("POST", "json_mysql_data.php", true);
            hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                    var d = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
                    arbitrarybox.innerHTML = d.arbitrary.returntime;
                    databox.innerHTML = "";
                    for(var o in d){
                        if(d[o].title){
                            databox.innerHTML += '<p><a href="page.php?id='+d[o].id+'">'+d[o].title+'</a><br>';
                            databox.innerHTML += ''+d[o].cd+'</p>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                hr.send("limit=4");
                databox.innerHTML = "requesting...";
                myTimer = setTimeout('ajax_json_data()',6000);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Timed JSON Data Request Random Items Script</h2>
        <div id="databox"></div>
        <div id="arbitrarybox"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">ajax_json_data();</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP code goes on a separate file called "json_mysql_data.php". I'm just following this tutorial from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Bv8P5oQnFw and it runs fine for him but not for me. I tested "connect_db.php" with mysql alone and it works fine. It seems to me like php doesn't go pass if (isset ($_POST['limit'])) but why...On the html file I get the "requesting..." message from the javascript code which means is waiting for PHP. Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: You do realize you're sending this HTML page as a JSON object? Also, you may want to use arrays and then output the json object made by passing that array to `json_encode()`. If you're going to use the same page, you should make sure that the HTML isn't being output when you request the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help @arielnmz. I found the problem. PHP was having issues with the `getDate()` function because the `date.timezone` field was not configured in the PHP.ini file. Adding the following line to the file fixed the problem:

```
date.timezone = "UTC"
```

Answer (score 1):

You check for the ready state and change the content of `databox` with the response JSON **inside** the `onreadystatechange` function:

```
hr.onreadystatechange = function(aEvt) {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        …
        databox.innerHTML += …;
        …
    }
    …
    databox.innerHTML = "requesting...";
    …
}
```

But you change the HTML of the `databox`:

```
databox.innerHTML = "requesting...";
```

Still **inside** the block of the `onreadystatechange` function and **after** you receive the response, so the `databox` will always say `"requesting..."` no matter what you receive. You have to move the part that prints `"requesting..."` outside of it:

```
hr.onreadystatechange = function(aEvt) {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        …
        databox.innerHTML += …;
        …
    }
    …
}
…
databox.innerHTML = "requesting...";
…
```

**Update**:

Also, it seems that your function ins't defined correctly, as you can see, the one on the [MDN reference pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) example receives a parameter:

```
req.onreadystatechange = function(aEvt) {
    …
}
```

But yours doesn't have such parameter:

```
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    …
}
```

Ans that's it.

Comment: What happens if you put an alert inside the function? Does it get displayed?

Comment: If I put it under "function ajax_json_data () {alert('working');} it gets displayed but if I put it inside the "hr.onreadystatechange(){alert('working');} it doesn't show.

Comment: Do you put it right at the beginning or inside the `if`?

Comment: Are your sure the server is valid? See my updated anser.

Comment: Yes. I'm running on my localhost

Comment: See my updated answer, it seems that your function may not be defined correctly.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try that and will let you know what happened.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found the problem. PHP was having issues with the getDate() function because the date.timezone was not configured in the PHP.ini file. LOL